# Make offsetting file contents during build

Tags: docker, makefile, dockerfile

I'm trying to use Make to ... make modular Dockerfiles. Long story short, I want to centralize certain elements and make the composable and reusable, like classes and functions really, but the Dockerfile syntax does not - and according to the developers, [*will* not](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/735) - offer any facilities in the image of C's `#include` or similar composability solutions. Not to worry, `#include` and friends to the rescue!
Except...

I have the following Makefile in my project:

```
BUILD_DIR := ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build

TEMPLATE_FILES := $(shell find ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} -name '*.build')
TEMPLATE_FILENAMES := $(foreach file,$(TEMPLATE_FILES),$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(file)).built)
BUILT_TEMPLATES := $(TEMPLATE_FILENAMES:.build.built=.built)

DOCKER_FILES := $(shell find ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} -name '*.Dockerfile')
DOCKER_OBJS := $(foreach file,$(DOCKER_FILES),$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(file)))

all: $(BUILT_TEMPLATES) $(DOCKER_OBJS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: $(TEMPLATE_FILES) $(BUILD_DIR) # build any templated Dockerfiles
    cpp -E -P -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $@) -I ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/modules $<
    sed -i 's/__NL__ /\n/g' $(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $@)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.Dockerfile: $(DOCKER_FILES) $(BUILD_DIR)
    cp $< $(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(@))

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -r $(BUILD_DIR)
```

The objective is to run the templated Dockerfiles through GCC to compile the `#include`s in them into proper Docker instructions, and just copy the rest of the files. Sounds simple enough.

Except that it looks like all the target files are "offset" from their sources - like the file *names* are correct, but the *contents* are from a file elsewhere in the list, and with no discernible order either.

---

One thing that I'm fairly sure is wrong - but even more wrong otherwise - is the line

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: $(TEMPLATE_FILES) $(BUILD_DIR) # build any templated Dockerfiles
```

By all manuals and documentation, it ought to be

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: %.build $(BUILD_DIR) # build any templated Dockerfiles
```

but that's even worse, because then Make just says `make: *** No rule to make target '/docker/build/runner-dart-2-18-firebase.built', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

I'm out of ideas here, along with my limited knowledge of Make. What am I missing to make Make make - sorry - my Dockerfiles?

Comment: Just a couple of new ideas in the pot, which might simplify things: (a) images that inherit from each other - i.e. a base image and then child/grandchild images that stem from that; (b) multi-stage Docker builds, where intermediate stages are built for the benefit of later states, but are then thrown away.

Comment: @halfer, I did think of multistage builds, but that would involve copying files and when you have APT-installed stuff, like a Dart SDK, that quickly becomes a nightmare, the exact thing I wanted to avoid. Extending an image into grandchild images was dropped because it could lead to a situation where a change in one image inadvertently breaks another image due to weird inheritances - the kind of unforeseen consequences I'm not prepared for. A modular build, on the other hand, allows me to `include` common components, and use macros to create parametric layers in the image on general templates.

Comment: I should think you can break an image either way. I assume the best defence for this is to test the image using an automated build, and only push the image after that gate has been passed.

Comment: I don't think your approach is bad, but I already hated Makefiles, and then I saw the fantastic answer below and hated them even more!  I would have a worry that if the Dockerfile is not deterministic then more risk is being introduced, not less. But, perhaps test automation is the answer here too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: $(TEMPLATE_FILES) $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Says that if make wants to build a target that matches that pattern, and it can find all the prerequisites, then the pattern rule matches and the recipe can be used.  Let's ignore `BUILD_DIR` (note that it's always a bad idea to list a directory as a prerequisite, but that's not causing this problem).  Suppose `TEMPLATE_FILES` is set to the value `./foo/foo.build ./bar/bar.build`.  Now the above rule expands to:

```
./build/%.built: ./foo/foo.build ./foo/bar.build ./build
```

What is the recipe?

```
cpp -E -P -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $@) -I ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/modules $<
```

First it's always wrong to create a file that is not exactly `$@` so you should use just `$@` not `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $@)`.  But more importantly, what will `$<` be set to?  It is always set to the first prerequisite, and the first prerequisite is *always* `./foo/foo.build`.  So every time you run this recipe, regardless of which `.built` file you're trying to create, you will always be preprocessing the *first* `.build` file.

Your idea that you want this instead:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: %.build $(BUILD_DIR)
```

is correct, in general.  Why do you get the error?  Because if you are trying to build the target `./build/foo.built`, then the stem (part that matches `%`) is `foo`.  Then make will look to see if the prerequisite `foo.build` exists or can be created, because you said the prerequisite is `%.build`.  That file does NOT exist and CANNOT be created (make doesn't know how to create it), because the file is `./foo/foo.build` not `foo.build` which is a totally different file.

You have three options.  You can either write separate rules for each source directory:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: foo/%.build
    ...
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: bar/%.build
    ...
```

Or, you can change your generated files so they are not all in the same directory but instead keep the source directory structure; you would change this:

```
TEMPLATE_FILENAMES := $(foreach file,$(TEMPLATE_FILES),$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(file)).built)
BUILT_TEMPLATES := $(TEMPLATE_FILENAMES:.build.built=.built)
```

to just this:

```
BUILT_TEMPLATES := $(patsubst %.build,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built,$(TEMPLATE_FILES))
```

then create the output directory as part of the recipe:

```
@mkdir -p $(@D)
cpp -E -P -o $@ -I ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/modules $<
sed -i 's/__NL__ /\n/g' $@
```

Or finally, you could [use VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) to tell make what directories to look in to find the `*.build` files:

```
VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(TEMPLATE_FILES)))
```

(note, you should choose only *one* of these options).

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive and informative answer, you've taught me a lot in a short span.
It *looks like* the `VPATH` option will be the winner, though I'll need to do some more testing to verify that indeed everything is in order. I'll mark your answer as the true one if everything passes, otherwise I'll come back with more questions.

Comment: Just to be clear in the third option, I mean you should combine using VPATH with using your pattern rule idea of `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.built: %.build`